# Date Picker after selecting an item on a dropdown

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, dropdown

I'm trying to create an Input field that has drop down values. And if a certain item (Select Date) is selected, I would want it to show a datepicker to be able to select a date.

My issues are:

1. The datepicker dialog doesn't pop-up right away if "Select Date" is selected. You have to click on the field again to show it.
2. After the "Select Date" is selected, the datepicker is now being displayed every time the field is clicked. The datepicker should only show when the "Select Date" is chosen.

Here is my code:

```js
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function() {
  var selectValue = $(this).attr('data-value');
  var selectText = $(this).attr('data-text');

  if (selectValue == 3) {
    $('#date_select').datepicker({
      daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
      autoclose: true,
      todayHighlight: true
    });
    $("#date_select").datepicker("show");
  } else {
    $("#date_select").val(selectText);
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<div id="pickDate" class="input-group dropdown date">
  <input type="text" id="date_select" class="form-control" data-toggle="dropdown" required/>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="date_menu">
    <li><a href="#" data-value="1" data-text="Soon">Soon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="2" data-text="Someday">Someday</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="3" data-text="Select Date">Select Date</a></li>
  </ul>
  <span class="input-group-addon" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span role="button" class="caret"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I'm using bootstrap datepicker.

Comment: what `selectValue` did you get in first attempt?

Comment: i got 3. i used alert(selectValue) on the "if" statement to test it.

Comment: The value of `selectValue` is always 3 after `click` event triggered for first time. Since the dropdown already changed to datepicker, it displayed date selection regardless the click event triggered more than once.

Comment: I fixed that by adding $('#pickDate').datepicker('remove'); at the end of the function. But I still have the issue of the datepicker dialog not showing is "Select Date" is selected.

Comment: which lib are you using for datepicker?

Comment: Bootstrap.Datepicker v1.6.4

Comment: I've updated the code with the css and javascripts.
it should show the actual dropdowns now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at modified code for issue #2

```
 $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function () {
  var selectValue = $(this).attr('data-value');
  var selectText = $(this).attr('data-text');
  if (selectValue == 3) {
  $('#pickDate').datepicker({
    daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
  });
    $('.ui-datepicker').css("display","block");
  }
  else {
    $('#date_select').val(selectText);

    $('.ui-datepicker').css("display","none");
  }
 });
```

This will show the datepicker only if you select option no 3 else it willbe hidden.

Let me know if it works for you.

For issue 1: Could you brief me about "You have to click on the field again to show it." What is your expected output?

Comment: thanks for this.
for issue 1, when i choose "Select Date" on the drop down, it doesn't show the datepicker dialog right away. You have to click on the field again to show the date picker.

i guess on the first time you clicked "Select Date", it only enables the datepicker but doesn't actually displays it.

Comment: Looks like when i click your code snippet and choose select date, it quickly displays datepicker.

Comment: Could you also accept the answer if it works for you!